# Bind event in coffee script constructor

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

If I have class

```
class Control
  constructor: (@canvas, @control) ->
    @control.on('keyup change', ->
      update(@canvas)
    )
```

When I change control, change event is fired and I got error `$canvas is undefined`.

However, if code is changed to

```
class Control
  constructor: (canvas, @control) ->
    @control.on('keyup change', ->
      update(canvas)
    )
```

everything works as expected.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as expected. Using `@` on a constructor parameter automatically sets `this.canvas = canvas` in our constructor. The context (`this`) of your event-handler is different than the class, unless you explicitly scope it with the "fat arrow" `=>`.

```
class Control
  constructor: (@canvas, @control) ->
    @control.on('keyup change', => # notice fat arrow
      update(@canvas)
    )
```

In your working example, you are *avoiding* the problem by not attaching `canvas` to the current context.